Xcode LaunchScreen.storyboard Error - an internal error occurred Editing functionality may be limited
Problem Description:
When Xcode tries to open a LaunchScreen.storyboard file, the error message "An internal error occurred.Editting functionality may be limited."
This issue causes xcode to stutter when Launch Screen is opened.
I'm currently trying to fix Launch Screen due to this issue, but I can't.
Xcode version in use:
16.0.0
To recreate the problem:
An error occurs when you open an existing project and select the LaunchScreen.storyboard file.
Whether the same error occurs with the new project.
Attempted Workaround:
Restart Xcode

Delete Derived Data
Reboot Mac
Clean Build

macOS version - macOS Sequoia 15.0
Hardware specifications in use- MacBook Pro M2
Question:
Is there any other way to fix this error?
If anyone has experienced a similar issue, please share what solution you have found.

Does this happen with a new project?

@benc Yes, I happened when I was trying to make LaunchScreen in a new project

Got it... I thought I'd be upgraded now so I could try it as well... but it won't be until tomorrow. I'll try to look at it then.
